# R: How to select a table from a schema in redshift using dplyr (function scr_postgres)?

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I have a connection with my db in redshift using dplyr (function scr_postgres), but because it is under a schema I can't select the table.

**trying to access without the schema I got an error:**

```
requests <- tbl(my_db, "sessions")
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation     "sessions" does not exist
```

**trying to access with the schema in one string I got an error:**

```
requests <- tbl(my_db, "analytics.sessions")
Erro: Table analytics.sessions not found in database
```

**trying to access with schema combining strings I got an error:**

```
requests <- tbl(my_db, c("analytics", "sessions"))
Erro: length(from) not equal to 1
```

**But in RPostgreSQL it works:**

```
dbExistsTable(my_db$con, c("analytics", "sessions"))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Can you show your table schema? Why does it give the error `Table snowplow_pivots.sessions not found in database ` when you query for `analytics.sessions`? From what I read in the manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf) you can not pass an array with 2 values to `dbExistsTable`. Where does the function `tbl` come from?

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid Thank you for highlighting this issue. I had changed the names for the sake of brevity.

tbl is a function from dplyr package.

Comment: ok, I didn't not you know you could directly query the database with a function from dplyr. But as I said, the last command does not seem right, because it only takes one character value and not an array. Can you show your database structure?

Comment: Can you set the search_path within dplyr?  That would set it at the session level, but depending on your setup, you could default it at the cluster level to include the analytics schema.

Comment: @mike_pdb that's it! thank you. I could set it and it worked:

    `my_db <- src_postgres(host="host", port="5439", dbname = "dbname", user = "user", password = "XXXX", options="-c search_path=analytics")`

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @mike_db [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458000/r-how-to-select-a-table-from-a-schema-in-redshift-using-dplyr-function-scr-pos?noredirect=1#comment52804865_32458000) I can set the schema in the search_path.

For that I need to set the [**options**] parameter at the opening of a connection with src_postgres:

```r
my_db <- src_postgres(host="host", port="5439", 
         dbname = "dbname", user = "user", password = "XXXX", 
         options="-c search_path=analytics")
```

Or, you can use something like it at the selecting of a table:

```
requests <- tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * from analytics.sessions WHERE 0=1"))
```

Comment: Thanks @mike_db & Renato.  The clutch insight for me was that you can wrap the select statement in sql() as a way of specifying the schema.  That's much more user friendly.